Being able to delete an accepted answer if the question is a duplicate
It is well known that if an ordinary user posts an answer which gets accepted, then the poster cannot delete it. I suppose that the idea is that, since the answer got accepted, it has some value and therefore it should be preserved.
However, this argument has very little value if the question turns out to be a duplicate. In this case, my suggestion is that the person who posted the accepted answer should be able to delete it. Of course, if the poster thinks that the answer offers some new insights with respect to the other question, they can always post it as an answer to that question.
I am aware of the existence of this suggestion about a user having the possibility of deleting its accepted answers, but it has nothing to do with duplicate questions; it's about low quality answers.

You can always flag the question and ask for it to be merged with the duplicate (the question will be deleted and the answer moved to the original).

Possibly related feature request - Merge answers but not question when closing as duplicate

Similar thing that was previously requested

I think there's a misunderstanding of duplicates - and that closure as a duplicate means the post and its answer has no value.
Someone can/might still come across the duplicate or main question, and while 'the same' the posts may have different approaches to the question or answer.
Just because its closed as a dupe does not mean it may not have value for someone/

A duplicates value is only in being a signpost, any good answers not already on the target should be added as answers there.

Hmm, you're very right that dupes don't always have the same answers. In fact, often more than one answer to the same question is more valuable. Maybe my proposal would work even better because of this fact, that we could trust hi-rep community members (who have the hypothetical privilege) to make the right call. They could (hopefully correctly) decide if the accepted answer is in fact too similar to the dupe's answer and then if so make the call to delete it. And obviously visa-versa.

@Starship The system seems to disagree with you there. Only dupes without answers get the automatic redirect; a dupe with answers is considered worth looking at by the system. Seeing how dupes rarely are exact, there’s lots of nuance that can be on a specific Q&A but isn’t suitable for the generic dupe target.

I’m not sure why answers possibly being useful means the author can’t be allowed to decide if they want to delete their answer. If this were about automatically deleting answers on dupes, sure, but for what is proposed here I don’t see why this is relevant.

Well the other aspect of it - someone spent the effort of writing an answer, and that answer (or question!) might help someone find an answer there or elsewhere. A duplicate is a signpost

@MisterMiyagi The lack of autoredirect is because there may be some answers of value yes...but those answer should still be merged...

I agree that this feature request would be overall beneficial, but I have my own counter-proposal that would achieve the same goal and would also prevent overkill.
On a few occasions I for one have written an answer that has been accepted, but then wanted to delete it when the question has been closed as a duplicate, and that the accepted answer of the duplicate is nearly identical to my accepted answer.
So what I have done in those situations is flagged my post in need of moderator attention, and asked them to delete it. Which they have.

So, in turn, my counter-proposal is to make deleting accepted answers as duplicates a privilege.

This is how I imagine it working, roughly:

My proposal is to 'prevent overkill' from lower-rep users, but it shouldn't affect high-rep users, who should know better.
Just like the close-post-privilege, high-rep users could automatically delete their own accepted answers of duplicate posts.
If a low-rep user wants to do the same, they could request so, and it would be placed in a review-queue for the high-rep users to review and potentially approve.


Now I know that implementing this would be a big change for a relatively uncommon situation, so that's a downside.
What reputation would be needed obtain this privilege, however, is something that  I have not considered.
